# Alternative methods for coverting formulas to values in Excel using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, bloomberg

I want to create a process to pull data from Bloomberg first and replace all the formulas by their values. So far, I have came up with two approaches. 1. Use BDH code to pull data first for a range of cells, and then paste everything as values after all the data populated. 2. Use the BDH code to pull data and paste it as value right away, before the code can execute the next cell. The following is my code (I used the 2nd approach):

```
For j = lastrow - 6 To lastrow
time = ActiveSheet.Cells(j, 1)
    For i = 3 To lastcol 'starts from Col C
    ticker = ActiveSheet.Cells(2, i).Value
    ActiveSheet.Cells(j, i).Formula = "= BDH(""" & ticker & """,""Last_Price"",""" & time & """,""" & time & """, ""days=a"", ""fill=p"")"
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:03"))
    ActiveSheet.Cells(j, i).Value = ActiveSheet.Cells(j, i).Value
    Next
Next
```

When I run this code on Bloomberg, it doesn't paste as values and they are still codes. I feel that the 3 sec in the Application.Wait is not long enough, but I want to change my whole method and don't want to count how many seconds to populate one value. Has anyone had experience with this and can provide a faster approach to populate values from Bloomberg? Although the 1st approach I mentioned above is also an alternative, but I prefer getting the values while populating the data. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I actually came up with an answer to my own problem.. But it still uses OnTime..Not sure if there are other ways to do it

```
Sub pulldata()
    For j = lastrow - 6 To lastrow
    time = ActiveSheet.Cells(j, 1)
        For i = 3 To lastcol 'starts from Col C
        ticker = ActiveSheet.Cells(2, i).Value
        ActiveSheet.Cells(j, i).Formula = "= BDH(""" & ticker & """,""Last_Price"",""" & time & """,""" & time & """, ""days=a"", ""fill=p"")"
        Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:03"), "pastespecial"
        Next
    Next
end sub
'start a new sub to terminate previous macro
sub pastespecial()
Dim lastrow As Integer
lastrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Dim lastcol As Integer
lastcol = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, ActiveSheet.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
Set myrange = Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(lastrow - 6, 3), ActiveSheet.Cells(lastrow, lastcol))
myrange.Value = myrange.Value

end sub
```